# Symfony2 - Nullable annotation option doesn't work

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I've added a property/column (community) to my existing Entity (device). I want the values in this column to be `null` by default, so I've done:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="community", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $community = null;
```

After that, I've updated the database with:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

but I'm getting:

```
ALTER TABLE device ADD community INT NOT NULL
```

So it seems that `nullable` option doesn't work, as it is inserting a `NOT NULL` field.

Comment: try to remove "= null" to the property and restart the command

Comment: @KernelFolla - Thanks for your suggestion, but I was just using the command in production environment. Solved just using `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --env=dev`.

Comment: If you want to have a default value for a private class property you should put that in the constructor. For example `$this->community = null`

Comment: @Peter - Indeed, not needed for default `null` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the command with production environment (default).

Solved the issue just using this command (with `--env=dev`):

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --env=dev
```

Comment: In Symfony 4.2 `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --env=dev --force`. I had simillar issue, where nullable field was generated as NOT NULL with `diff` or normal `schema:update`.